# How to get ListItem Url to items display form?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How can i retrieve the items full url to its display form? I tried for example

```
string itemUrl = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl]);
```

but i get the following result which is not working:

> http://sp2013/sites/104/Lists/Sharepointtasks/13_.000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
string itemUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}?ID={2}", properties.Web.Url, properties.List.Forms[PAGETYPE.PAGE_DISPLAYFORM].Url, properties.ListItem.ID);
```

This works fine:

> http://sp2013/sites/104/Lists/Sharepointtasks/DispForm.aspx?ID=14